# Comparing 2 Arrays in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

I have read the contents of a folder and store them in an array. And need to pass this array to a script. How can I store and pass the array and read that array??

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

cd /path/applications-war
arrayWar=( $(ls /path/applications-war))
```

I need all the contents under this folder into an array (@arrayWar).
I will login into another box and call a script. I need to pass this array to the script.

```
/usr/bin/ssh -t -t username@machinename /path/myscript.sh @arrayWar
```

Inside **myscript.sh**, I want to compare the passed array @arrayWar with ServicesArray.

```
#!/bin/ksh
 @arrayWar = $1
 ServicesArray=('abc.war' 'xyz.war')
   for warfile in @arrayWar
     do
       if  echo "${ServicesArray[@]}" | fgrep  "$warfile"; then
            echo "$warfile matches"
       else
            echo "$warfile not matched" 
       fi
    done
```

Comment: really, ksh with spaces around your `=` sign? Don't you get an error message? Good luck.

Comment: @fedorqui: My issue is not with white spaces. It is to pass elements into an array and compare two arrays.

Comment: You cannot pass arrays in shells; you can only pass the contents of an array as a sequence of positional arguments.

Comment: @chepner How can I pass the contents of an array?

Comment: @sravs448 `"${arrayWar[@]}"` (double quotes essential) expands to the contents of that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your script, which takes a variable number of files as arguments:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ServicesArray=('abc.war' 'xyz.war')

for warfile in "${@##*/}"
  do
   if  echo "${ServicesArray[@]}" | fgrep  "$warfile"; then
        echo "$warfile matches"
   else
        echo "$warfile not matched" 
   fi
 done
```

You call your script like this (note that using `ls` is not recommended):

```
arrayWar=( /path/applications-war/* )
/usr/bin/ssh -t -t username@machinename /path/myscript.sh "@{arrayWar[@]}"
```

You can also dispense with `arrayWar`, and pass the list of files directly

```
/usr/bin/ssh -t -t username@machinename /path/myscript.sh /path/applications-war/*
```

Comment: If I pass just the list of files directly, will "$@" will have the list for comparing?

Comment: Yes. From your script's perspective, the two are equivalent. `${arrayWar[@]}` and `/path/applications-war/*` are expanded by the shell to identical lists of words.

Comment: I tried `/path/applications-war/*` . But its showing all as not matched, even though the list contains the elements in ServiceArray. Because its listing as `\path\applicatipns-war\abc.war` and `\path\applications-war\xyz.war`.  And its comparing that with abc.war and xyz.war. Hence everything is printing as not matched. How can get only `abc.war` and `xyz.war` or do we need to change the way we are doing the grep ??

Comment: I have edited the above code to get only `abc.war` and `xyz.war` into an array. But I am getting an error near the awk statement.  `line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: My apologies; I forgot that the bare wildcard would include the full path name, where calling `ls` gives only the base name.

Answer (score 0):

As chepner pointed out, you can't pass the array, but there are a couple of ways around that.  The first would be to pass them as a series of positional arguments, I believe the limit on those is 9.  If you have more than 9 items in that array, or you would like to do this in a more permanent manner, you could also fairly easily write this in BASH (I'm not familiar with ksh, I did a quick Google and the syntax appears fairly similar).  I'll use the output of ls in this example

```
\#!/bin/bash


\# Lets say this gives it 'myFile' and 'testFile'
ls > myArrayFile

\# Need to change IFS to accurately split the list, this splits by newline
IFS=$’\x0a’

\# Set your array
compareArray=('myFile' 'testFile' 'someOtherStuff')

\# Standard loop to compare arrays

for genItem in `cat myArrayFile`;
do
    for staticItem in $compareArray;
    do
    if $genItem == $staticItem;
        then
        echo "$genItem is in the static array"
    fi
done
done
```